# Get-ADGroup with filter isn't working for all

Tags: powershell, adgroup

I got a problem with my powershell script, I need to get all users from group, I have the group id which I can use to get the group. The problem I have is that my solution isn't working for all group and I don't get what is wrong.

I have some group name
eAM
eGR
eTE
eDF
eMP-arts
e-CV

The 3 first isn't working and the other one yes.  Here the script I use

```
$like = "*" + $branch
foreach ($member in (Get-ADGroupMember (Get-ADGroup -filter {name -like $like}))){
    # Do something
}
```

And the error I get for which isn't working
Get-ADGroupMember : can't convert «System.Object[]» in `«Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADGroup», 
requiered by «Identity» param. The specified method is not supported
+ Get-ADGroupMember (Get-ADGroup -filter {name -like "*AM"})
+                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument : (:) [Get-ADGroupMember], ParameterBindingException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : cannotConvertArgument,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADGroupMember`

Thanks in advance for your help,
MYT

Comment: `Get-ADGroupMember` expects as the Identity parameter something unique like a SamAccountName. If your query for the ADGroup has a result other than a single group it wont work. Try to query for the ADGroup before and use a `Foreach` loop. If you know the exact group names, why don't you use it?

Comment: @Olaf you're right, there is multiple group who finish by my name, I'll use the OU to do it. I don't have the exact name, I've only the shortname (I use `AM` to find `G-eAM)

Comment: So you should determine the exact group names before you query the members.

Comment: I can't determine the exact group name cause someone hase `G-eSomething` and other `G-Something` and I don't get the `e`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error thells you that `Get-ADGroupMember` does not accept an array of groups, but a single group. You'd also get errors if `Get-AdGroup` would not return any results. Instead, pipe the commands:

```
Get-ADGroup -Filter {name -like $like} | Get-ADGroupMember | Foreach-Object {
}
```

Please note that accounts can belong to multiple groups so same member could be returned multiple times.